# 1-Way ANOVA with single independent/repeated (within/between) factor

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, independence

I want to perform an ANOVA on data with a single factor with three levels. The difficulty for me is that two of the levels are repeated measures (within subjects) and the third level is independent measurements (between subjects). How can I setup the anova in R? Is there a non-parametric test as well similar to the Friedman?

Here is some example data that demonstrates my values. Note that id values 1 to 5 are repeated across conditions A and B. I want to know the main effect of condition.

```
 id condition       value
  1         A  2.02007736
  2         A  1.89103975
  3         A  0.14934483
  4         A -0.06426685
  5         A  2.29443309
  1         B  1.03682968
  2         B  3.61084808
  3         B  2.61471544
  4         B -1.05105853
  5         B  3.36151584
  6         C  0.91556132
  7         C  2.33281852
  8         C  4.24242955
  9         C  2.21116219
 10         C  4.48222818
```

```
# R code for created data with n observations per condition
n <- 30
data <- data.frame(
    id = factor(c(1:n, 1:(n*2))),
    condition=factor(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each=n)),
    value = c(rnorm(n, 1), rnorm(n, 2), rnorm(n, 3)) + # observation variability
        c(rep(rnorm(n, 0, 0.5), times=2), rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)) # subject variability
)
# Can I just do a repeated measures analysis? (probably not)
summary(aov(value ~ condition + Error(id/condition), data=data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lme` (in **nlme** package) or `lmer` (**lme4** package) to fit a model that incorporates subject information and sorts it out correctly.  For instance:

```
library(nlme)
mymodel <- lme(value ~ condition, random = ~ 1 | id, data = data)
summary(mymodel)
```

The `aov` function is not a good choice here because it really does not work well for any but the classical balanced designs. Your proposed model specifies error strata for `id/condition`, but the implied `id:condition` stratum corresponds to individual observations -- hence is not a grouping criterion, and it should be omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I call summary on mymodel I get the individual t-tests for each variable. Does anova(mymodel) produce the ANOVA I am looking for?

Comment: try it! (But you might in general prefer `Anova` in the **car** package, as it does marginal tests when there is more than one factor.) You can also use the **lsmeans** or **effects** package to obtain means and comparisons.